# how to create a plugin for google chrome that automatically shuts down the system

Tags: java, javascript

i have a java code for automated shut down of a system.
the code is as follows:-

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class sd
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int wholeTimeBeforeShutdown=0;

        int hour=0;
        int minute=0;
        int second=0;

        try
        {
            String a=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"HOUR","HOUR BEFORE SHUTDOWN",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            String b=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"MINUTE","MINUTE BEFORE SHUTDOWN",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            String c=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"SECOND","SECOND BEFORE SHUTDOWN",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            if((a==null)||a.equals(""))
            {
                a="0";
            }
            if((b==null)||b.equals(""))
            {
                b="0";
            }
            if((c==null)||c.equals(""))
            {
                c="0";
            }

            int e=Integer.parseInt(a);
            int f=Integer.parseInt(b);
            int g=Integer.parseInt(c);

            wholeTimeBeforeShutdown=wholeTimeBeforeShutdown+((e*60)*60);
            wholeTimeBeforeShutdown=wholeTimeBeforeShutdown+((f*60));
            wholeTimeBeforeShutdown=wholeTimeBeforeShutdown+(g);
            wholeTimeBeforeShutdown=wholeTimeBeforeShutdown*1000;

            Thread.sleep(wholeTimeBeforeShutdown);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -s -t 00 -f");
        }

            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

i want to make use of the this code to create a plugin for google chrome that shuts down the system automatically. i know how to add a plug in to the chrome web browser.that involves doing all sorts of coding and placing them in a folder and loading that folder into web browser.
my question is how to use this code to make a "plug in" for google chrome?

Comment: Why do you need to shut down the system from Chrome?!?

Comment: i am doing a project on plug-ins for chrome in which i am supposed to shut down the system using a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

*"i am doing a project on plug-ins for chrome ..."*.

OK.  Here's a couple of hints to get you started ...

- In order to execute a command, a java applet or a javascript plugin has to be true
- In order to do privileged stuff (like shutting down a system), you typically require "root" privilege (on a Linux system).
- Google "chrome java plugin".